# Codeigniter: Calculate average and display in view

Tags: database, codeigniter, average

I need to calculate in a function the average score of a column named: `tot_score` from my database table `scores_primary` I tried some codes but I am not getting anything. Any idea how I can do this?

## Model

```php
function calculateaverage($student_id){
  $query = $this->db->select('AVG(tot_score) as  average_score')->from('scores_primary')->where('student_id', $student_id)->get();
    return $query->row()->average_score;
}
```

## Controller

```php
function index(){
  $data['avg'] = $this->primary_model->calculateaverage();
  $this->load->view('student/studentshow', $data);
}
```

## View

```php
<span><b>AVERAGE RESULT:</b><?php echo $avg; ?></span>
```

I have been on this for days now. I still don't know where the problem lies.
Average result still shows blank.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to supply a `$student_id` parameter to the `calculateaverage` function :

```
$data['avg'] = $this->primary_model->calculateaverage($student_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `$student_id` to the model.

```
function index(){
$data['avg'] = $this->primary_model->calculateaverage($student_id);
$this->load->view('student/studentshow', $data);
}
```